# Suitable expression for value in defeat?

Tags: expressions

When someone loses a match, I want to tell him that this loss can make him strong, that in the end this will help him to be a winner.

Is there any expression in English for **defeat is the prerequisite for victory**?

Comment: I feel like you could apply an expression from any one of those platitude-laden motivational posters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way of saying it straight would be:

```
Each time you fall, pick yourself up, (dust yourself off) and try again.
```

You could also remind them that:

```
That which doesn't kill us makes us stronger
```

Finally, and more obscurely:

```
Up from the ashes, grow the roses of success
(sometimes abbreviated to "from the ashes...")
```

which derives from/was used in a song in the film [Chitty Chitty Bang Bang (sound required)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GND10sWq0n0)

That last one is often used to mean when information/plans from a failed project are reused in the next one, you say that the next project "grew from the ashes" of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the origin of this, but it applies: Success is built on 100 mistakes.